# pear install Console_getopt on centos 7

Tags: centos7, freepbx, pear

I am trying to run the command below on CentOS 7 (hosted on OVH) server as a step to install `freepbx`. Please check the error and suggest any fix if possible.

```
]# pear install Console_getopt

No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Console_getopt"
install failed
```

Here's what i get when i try to install `php-pear`

```
]# yum install php-pear

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do*
```

Some quick help would be appreciated.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble: Use a FreePBX Distro ISO image to install your server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton only if OVH provided the distro.

Comment: Huh? Which OVH service do you have?